# Is it possible to only show xAxis labels when there is data in iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and am plotting a single value for each day that data was collected on a line chart. I only want an xAxis label and line if there's data for that day.

But iOS charts is laying out the xAxis labels for every day.

Y values range from 1 to 5, and X values are number of days ago

So if there is data from 23 day ago and data from 34 days ago and no data in between, I only want to show the two days on the chart.

```
let yValues: [ChartDataEntry] = [
    ChartDataEntry(x: 23, y: 3.0),
    ChartDataEntry(x: 34, y: 2.0)
]
```

I want no more than 6 days visible on x axis so I set:

```
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
```

But it's showing all empty days between 23 and 34:

[image]

So how do you suppress the labels/lines 24-33?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

First try disable xAxis  Now 23-29 will not showing.

```
chartView.xAxis.enabled = false
```

After you don't like this answer, you must try this;

```
chartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
```

now you want only show 6 day; try add this line after

```
lineChart.data = yourData
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)
lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(6)
```

Comment: `xAxis.enabled = false` and `xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false` simply remove the labels and lines but don't compress the data so that only days with data are visible. Still only 1 data point is visible. iOS Charts is making space for each day regardless of whether that day has data. That's the issue. And... `setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6)` is already set.

Comment: is there any solution for this problem? @lilbiscuit ?

Comment: @KishoreKankata if you use setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6) and setVisibleXRangeMinimum(6) your problem will be solved :)